# C++ Multi-level Class Template Constructors Do Not Compile

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, multi-level

The following multi-level class templates do not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class A {
private:
  A(void);
  T _num_;
public:
  A(T num): _num_(num){};
  void printNum(void){

    cout << _num_ << "\n";

  }
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
private:
  B(void);
public:
  B(T num): A(num){};
};

class C : public B<int> {
private:
  C(void);
public:
  C(int num): B(num){};
};

int main()
{
  /* code */
  auto c = C(2);

  c.printNum();
  return 0;
}
```

> error: member initializer 'A' does not name a non-static data member or base class B(T num): A(num){};
>
> error: member initializer 'B' does not name a non-static data member or base class
>     C(int num): B(num){};

However removing the templates complies without issue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
  A(void);
  int _num_;
public:
  A(int num): _num_(num){};
  void printNum(void){

    cout << _num_ << "\n";

  }
};

class B : public A {
private:
  B(void);
public:
  B(int num): A(num){};
};

class C : public B {
private:
  C(void);
public:
  C(int num): B(num){};
};

int main()
{
  /* code */
  auto c = C(2);

  c.printNum();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was a syntax error.  The typename T must be passed to the base ctor calls in the derived class ctor definition in addition to the class inheritance declaration.

```
class B : public A<T> {//...
B(T num): A<T>(num){}; //NOTE: <T> added to A ctor call.
```

and

```
class C : public B<int> {//...
C(int num): B<int>(num){};  //NOTE: <int> added to B ctor call.
```

Full compiling code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class A {
private:
  A(void);
  T _num_;
public:
  A(T num): _num_(num){};
  void printNum(void){

    cout << _num_ << "\n";

  }
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
private:
  B(void);
public:
  B(T num): A<T>(num){};
};

class C : public B<int> {
private:
  C(void);
public:
  C(int num): B<int>(num){};
};

int main()
{
  /* code */
  auto c = C(2);

  c.printNum();
  return 0;
}
```